# How do I list total number of records with similar name in SQL?

Tags: sql, syntax

Sorry for the bad title, I couldn't think of a way to describe it.

I have a SQL table that contains utility poles and their construction spec and the quantity.

I need to create a query that will list each construction spec and the quantity.

For example:

```
Table- Poles

         Type, Spec, Quanity    
Record1- Pole, A5-1, 4
Record2- Pole, C4-1, 2
Record3- Pole, A5-4, 3
Record4- Pole, C4-1, 3
```

And I need a query that would return:

```
Table- Spec Totals

Spec, Quantity
A5-1, 4
C4-1, 5
A5-4, 3
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "similar" or "the same" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GROUP BY` allows you to use various [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en///group-by-functions.html). In this case, `SUM()`.

```
SELECT Spec, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity FROM Poles GROUP BY Spec
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a group by statement would work well in this scenario.

```
SELECT Spec, SUM(Quantity) FROM Poles GROUP BY Spec
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT spec, SUM(Quanity)
FROM Poles
GROUP BY Spec
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select spec, sum(quantity) total from table_name group by spec;
```